# Why do floats keep a "phantom" space when they escape to the next line?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm playing around with properties of CSS elements and wrote this code:

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}
.parent {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.col {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    }
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: white;
}
p:hover {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

Why is it that when I run the result and resize the screen to the point where the blue float clears to the next line, the yellow outline of the parent div doesn't resize to fit the width?

I apologize if that is confusing. Here is a visual example of what I mean:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r7mhizfqdbyflh/Screenshot%202014-12-24%2001.02.36.png?dl=0

Why is there the yellow space left over despite it being inline-block? Is it because float keeps reserved space there even though it's cleared to the next line?

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ffxg9qq0/1/embedded/result/

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question. The behavior is intuitive and consistent across all browsers, but the spec never really explains it. The closest I can find is rule #7 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position): "A left-floating box that has another left-floating box to its left may not have its right outer edge to the right of its containing block's right edge. (Loosely: a left float may not stick out at the right edge, unless it is already as far to the left as possible.) An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements."

Comment: ... which explains why a float may overflow its containing block if it is the first in the line but not otherwise, but it doesn't explain why the containing block doesn't shrink to fit just the ones that do. The accepted answer makes no attempt to explain the behavior as the question asks, instead offering a workaround to an imagined problem, and in fact the "reasoning" given is just begging the question altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock - I don't think that's it. I think it's a consequence of the shrink-to-fit algorithm. CSS 2.1 spec says "Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. ... Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of [margins, borders paddings & scroll bars]. Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(pref minimum width, available width), preferred width).

Comment: ... In the case of the float wrapping, that evaluates to the available width.

Comment: @Alohci: Yeah, that makes sense. I suspect it had something to do with available width, but I was probably overthinking how it would boil down to that. Of course it makes sense - "available width" ought to mean as *much* as is available, and not as *little*. So there is no reason the containing block should shrink to fit just the floating elements that fit on one line - that would be the preferred minimum width instead.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting discussion guys! So could someone explain to me how this available width concept works? Happy holidays to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the space was cause due to `float:left` of the children

you will need to write `@media` query so that the `.parent` adjusts

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .col{
        float:none;
    }    
}
```

resize the below fiddle to `max-width` `400px`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ffxg9qq0/3/

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.col {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  float: left;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  color: white;
}
p:hover {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .col {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='col green'>
    <p>I'm in a green float!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col red">
    <p>I'm in a red float!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col blue">
    <p>I'm in a blue float!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. So when floats are set to float left, they do leave this extra space there when they move to the next line?

Comment: yes even `display:inline-block` element leaves space