# How to shrink wrap floating content?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem concerning shrink wrapping a container div, if the content is floating.

I want the container to be only as wide as the floating content of the container (shrink-wrapped). The container should be centered. Because of the context I cannot give the container an absolute width.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Some content</div>
    <div class="content">Some content</div>
    <div class="content">Some content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
   width: 50px;
   float: left;
   background-color: #CCC;
   margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
   overflow:hidden;
}


.container:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    display:table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Please see the problem under https://jsfiddle.net/jackis/05nzo4oc/12/. As soon as the floating content has to break the line the container takes the whole available width, even if a good part of the container remains empty to the right then. If the content does not break the line it works as expected. To see that, change the width of the .content class to 50px:

```
.content { width: 50px; ...}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to shrink wrap the container div if the floating content has to break the line.

Edit:

The container should contain as much content divs as possible in one line, but should leave no "phantom space" to the right, if the next content div uses the next line. For the real world problem I am trying to demonstrate with this model the width of the content divs is fixed.

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is too much things going wrong here, you dont need `display: block;` if you floating your element and  you have repeated `.content:after`  also there is nothing like `auto` for `padding` property

Comment: This phenomenon is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632910/why-do-floats-keep-a-phantom-space-when-they-escape-to-the-next-line), although that question asks *why* exactly it happens and there hasn't been an authoritative answer as to that. I am not sure if questions exist that ask for workarounds.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes I experience exactly the same problem, but the proposed solution does not work in my case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem based on knowledge I have about the context of the environment the composition is used. As the container takes the whole width of the screen and I know how wide a content tile is, I know how many can fit in one line. I can then work with media queries and set the width of the container explicitely to get the desired behavior:

```
`@media all and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width:559px) {
    div.product-grid {
        width:280px;
    }
 }

@media all and (min-width: 560px) and (max-width:839px) {
    div.product-grid {
        width:560px;
    }
 }
```

`

The container will then be centered. on the screen. Of course I can not foresee all possible screen widths, but for huge resolutions, I can just live with a container not being centered.

Answer (score 0):

To get a container block to expand to fit it's children you need to set it to inline-block. This also gives the possibility to center it using text-align center on a parent element.

```
.content {
width: 270px;
display:block;
float: left;
background-color: #CCC;
margin: 0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.content:nth-child(odd){
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 560px;
}

.outer-wrap {
  text-align: center
}
```

I have forked and tidied up your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/simoncmason/qL611mu6/

I take it this is what you wanted to achieve.

(Edited following comments)

Comment: your version doesn't work if you set width 270px on the content on Chrome

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am afraid, that it does not solve my problem. The width of the content divs is fixed in the real world problem. I can also not give a max-width to the container, as it should accomodate to different resolutions. My problem is the "phantom space" mentioned in the 2nd comment after my post. The container should use as much space as possible, but it should end right after the break to the next content div.

Comment: @Bogdan.Nourescu The optional max-width:500px will break when the content is set to 270px - just increase the max width. Jackis - what is the required fixed width in the real world problem? I think if you just remove the max-width rule and set the content the width you want it will work, you will also need to change the % margin on the nth-child(odd) to say 20px.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle in my answer, now working with a fixed width content element.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it right with the width 270px and other versions, but i feel it to be a hack:

```
.container {
    padding: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    display:table-caption;
    margin-left:-50%;
    margin-right:50%;

}
```

A complete version is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/05nzo4oc/16/).