# Shrink parent div to unknown number of floating children (css or js)

Tags: jquery, css, width, parent

I have a parent div (display:table) that wraps an unknown number of floating children.
I now want it to always have the width of the children's rows.

In other words: If the parent div is wider or narrower than a multiple of it's children, unused space remains within the parent div. - How can I avoid this?

Is it possible with css only or do I need JS to calculate the width of the rows inside and give it to the parent div?

Here's the simplified code:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table;
    width:90%;
}
.child {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">Text</div>
    <div class="child">Text</div>
    <div class="child">Text</div>
    <div class="child">Text</div>
    <div class="child">Text</div>
    <div class="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

Please play with the width of your browser to see the unused white space on the right side.

Comment: can you explain how you want exactly as a image?

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Why do floats keep a "phantom" space when they escape to the next line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632910/why-do-floats-keep-a-phantom-space-when-they-escape-to-the-next-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3qa1fmht/)**

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.child {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    order: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I was writing almost same answer :) but you is better

Comment: nice and very useful answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   .wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table;
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.child {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    width: 24.25%;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 1% 1% 0 0;  
}
.child:nth-child(-n+4){
    margin-top: 0;
}

.child:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Check out this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wtxafjw0/1/

This assumes minimum of 4 child elements and the child width is in % to force them take up the entire space horizontally.